# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table has no such column

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, insert

So I guess it is a very common issue, searching the web I found that I am not the only one who faced a such issue and yes I know that there is a question with almost the same title, however that did not help to solve the issue I am facing ... so let's start from the beginning

I am simply trying to insert into a table that I created. 
This table has three columns: "id", "name", "value", and was created as following

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "cookie";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_VALUE = "val";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "commments.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

// Database creation sql statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
  + TABLE_NAME + "(" 
  + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
  + COLUMN_VALUE + "text not null, "
  + COLUMN_NAME + " text not null"
  + ");";

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
  database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}
```

Now I am trying to insert into this table as following

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, "username");
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_VALUE, username);

        long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        nameValuePair newComment = cursorToNameValuePair(cursor);
        cursor.close();
```

However I am getting this error

```
table cookie has no column named val
```

I searched for similar issues online, most of the solution where talking about a change happened to the database so I need to either

1- Un-install the application before trying to run in debugging mode again
2- update the database version from 1 to 3

However that did not help .. So looking forward for your solutions :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is here

```
+ COLUMN_VALUE + "text not null, "
```

into `DATABASE_CREATE` String. You missed space between *column name* and *column type*.

It should be

```
+ COLUMN_VALUE + " text not null, "
```